# ADF DataFlows Last Entry in a column

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, dataflow, azure-data-factory

Apologies if this has been asked previously, as I've been searching and still haven't found anything helpful. If it is, please point me in the right direction.

Okay so the issue is, I have a table with the columns, **EquipmentId** and **OperatingHours**. The data is something like this,

```
| EquipmentId | OperatingHours |
|    1020     |      3577      |
|    1020     |      3577      |
|    1020     |      3580      |
|    1020     |      3581      |
|    1020     |      3585      |
```

I want to get the last Entry based on the **EquipmentId** so that I could get the value **3585**, I've tried using **Aggregate** using **Group By EquipmentId** and under **Aggregations** something like this,

[image]

But I am still getting **3577** in the output and not the last entry.

My question is, How can I get the last entry value only using DataFlows, is there anything else I could use instead of Aggregate to sort this out.

Apologies if I've done something wrong, it's my first day working with DataFlows so just trying to follow different tutorials available online.

Thank you and looking forward to hearing from any of you.

Comment: Is the OpreatingHours bigger, the later it  inserted(last entry)?

Comment: First, check the ordering of the data from the transformation just prior to this aggregate. Look at the data preview to see the order. To maintain that order, you might have to move everything into a single partition.You can set that by choosing "single partition" on the transformation just prior to this aggregate.

Comment: Yes OperationalHours increase with time, it refers to machinery referred with EquipmentId and it's hours of Operation, so it will increase gradually.

Comment: Hi @rac3b3nn0n, did the error solved now?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same operation, but I get the value '3585'.

Please ref my steps bellow:

Source settings and data preview:

[image]

Aggregate settings and data preview:
[image]

I think we have the same operations. Please correct me if I missed anything.
Maybe you can try again.